# Setting dynamic Img src using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am very very new to JavaScript. and would appreciate any help i can get on this. I'm trying to create a script that takes imgsrc dynamically, and displays image for the logged in user.

ex: `https://sampleimage.com/?uid=user1`
`https://sampleimage.com/?uid=user2`
`https://sampleimage.com/?uid=user3`
`https://sampleimage.com/?uid=user4`

I managed to come up with the below, But it does not work. what am i missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var imgsrc = "https://sampleimage.com/?uid=userid"
        document.getElementById('img-circle').setAttribute('src', imgsrc);
</script>

<img alt="Badge Photo" class="img-circle" src="empty.jpg" title="crakesh" height="40" width="38"/>
```

Comment: Your code is running before your element exists, and you set `img-circle` to be the class not the id, so getElementById will not work in this case

Comment: is there a equivalent of getElementById  in javascript for class. i tried "getElementsbyClassName" but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image holder where you are trying to set image don't have `img-circle` id. You could use the class to select the element and set image.

```
<img alt="Badge Photo" class="img-circle" src="empty.jpg" title="crakesh" height="40" width="38"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var imgsrc = "https://sampleimage.com/?uid=userid"
  document.querySelector('.img-circle').setAttribute('src', imgsrc);
</script>
```

Alternatively you could add id to your `img` element

```
<img alt="Badge Photo" id="img-circle" class="img-circle" src="empty.jpg" title="crakesh" height="40" width="38"/>
```

But if you have multiple image elements then having same id on multiple elements won't work.
Also make sure you are adding script before then end `</body>` tag or wrapping your code in `window.onload = function(){}`
Learn more about window.onload https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 0):

The script will run before the image tag is loaded. You can either wrap your code in a `window.onload = function() { ... }` or you can put your script tag after the image tag.

Comment: i was using img-circle to be the class not the id, so getElementById did not work. i am still trying to make it work with the class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

`"https://sampleimage.com/?uid=userid"`

You need to insert the user's ID in `userid`, or else you will just be querying the string `userid`. So:

`https://sampleimage.com/?uid=" + userID`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the link was just an example and was not the actual problem. and the issue was addressed below